# CakePHP 3.x - Email to log instead of sending during debug

Tags: email, cakephp, logging, cakephp-3.0

I would like to switch my application to a configuration where email isn't actually send, but instead saved to a log file.
This way I can test my application normally without being afraid of accidentally emailing to hundreds of users and without spamming myself.

I figured something with `EmailTransports` could be a solution. For instance, when using the `DebugTransport` the emails aren't send at all, the mail content is instead only returned by the `->send()` function.

The downside of this transport is than I have to modify controller code in order to display the content, which I would like to avoid.

So is there a configuration such that email is stored to files instead of being sent, e.g.:

```
[root]
    logs/
         emails/
             2019-10-01_15:32_email@example.com.txt
             2019-10-01_16:54_another_recipient@example.com.txt
             ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such built-in configuration, no, but you can easily create your own custom transport that logs emails to files instead of sending them.

Here's a very basic example transport that extends the debug transport, and writes the data to a custom [**logging scope**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/logging.html#logging-scopes):

```
namespace App\Mailer\Transport;

use Cake\Log\LogTrait;
use Cake\Mailer\Email;
use Cake\Mailer\Transport\DebugTransport;
use Psr\Log\LogLevel;

class TestTransport extends DebugTransport
{
    use LogTrait;

    public function send(Email $email)
    {
        $data = parent::send($email);
        $this->log(json_encode($data), LogLevel::DEBUG, ['scope' => ['emails']]);

        return $data;
    }
}
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > Email > Using Transports > Creating Custom Transports](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/core-libraries/email.html#creating-custom-transports)**